# How to make a node in a euler tour tree to be the tree root?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph

Prof. Eric mentioned in MIT 6.851 that it is possible to make a vertex into the tree root in a dynamic graph implemented by Euler Tour Tree. However, I just failed to achieve this goal.

For example, here is a euler tour sequence:

```
0 2 0 1 6 1 3 5 3 1 0
```

If we want to make node 1 into the root, we should get a sequence like:

```
1 6 1 3 5 3 1 0 2 0 1
```

However, for the previous root vertex 0, it seems impossible to find out its last visit node pointer in the new tree.

Any workaround?

Comment: Please read [mcve]. Questions on SO should be self-contained as much as possible. Your question can't be understood properly without looking up external sources.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? To compute the updated Euler tour faster than *O(n)*? Computing it in *O(n)* is trivial with a depth-first traversal from the new root.